# node-canvas importing .ttf file into TS for registerFont

Tags: node.js, typescript, fonts, node-canvas

I want to use local fonts (ttf format) in a canvas created by `node-canvas`.

I've created a typings file and added it to my `tsconfig`:

**fonts.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.ttf';
```

and my fonts are imported and registed:

**fonts/index.ts**

```
import * as Font_ComicSans from './comic-sans.ttf';

const Fonts = {
    Font_ComicSans
};

export default Fonts;
```

**component.ts**

```
import Fonts from '../fonts';
import { registerFont } from 'canvas';
...
registerFont(Font_ComicSans, { family: 'Comic Sans' });
```

However, when the code runs I get the error:

> "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './comic-sans.ttf'"

I'm using Typescript and NodeJS. Is this the wrong way to import a font (to be used like this)?

<sub>I won't use Comic Sans ever again, I promise.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just import the font directly in the `registerFont` function like this:

`registerFont('./comic-sans.ttf', { family: 'Comic Sans')`